# Autorefresh Gridview with updated data using ajax c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I am trying to automatically update my gridview with the updated data using ajax in c#. I tried making an ajax post which calls my c# method which then gets the updated data and binds to the gridview. But for some reason, the data in the gridview doesn't seem to change. Even though, during debug, I can see that the datatable has changed and I have the correct data. Where could I be doing wrong.

```
public static Dbconfig d = new Dbconfig();
   public static DataTable dr = new DataTable();
   public static GridView gr = new GridView();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gr = Rssfeed;
    }



[WebMethod]
    public static void updatefeed()
    {
        gr.DataSource = null;
       DataTable ds = d.ViewFeeddatabymostViewedfeed();
        gr.DataSource = ds;
        gr.DataBind();


    }



function UpdateGrid() {

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "Home.aspx/updatefeed",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                dataType: "json",

                success: OnSuccess,

                failure: function (response) {

                    //alert(response.d);

                }

            });

        }

        function OnSuccess(response) {

           // alert(response.d);

        }
```

I am using the setinterval function to make an Ajax post to my method after every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation today where I was making an asynchronous call to a method to update certain data in the database as well as reflect the same in the gridview. The solution I used was

```
protected void UpdateData(){
//do some stuff such that the data in the db is changed
gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Note that the gridview was placed in an Ajax UpdatePanel control.